# server-side & client-side templating engine for Java

Tags: javascript, java, html, web-services, templating

Are there any alternatives to [duel engine](https://bitbucket.org/mckamey/duel/wiki/Examples)? We would like to use it but there's not enough documentation and downloadable examples. Perhaps something more popular and tested would be preferable. We are looking to generate server-side templates and then pass the template as an object to a view using ajax requests. It would also be beneficial if we didn't **have** to send the entire template on each request but if we had the option to send snippets from start div to end div for example. We also really like the idea of using REST services to provide templates to clients.

Comment: Did you find anything since?

Comment: Just found out about this, by Google: https://developers.google.com/closure/templates/docs/javascript_usage
Seems to be more documented :)

Comment: I know Velocity http://velocity.apache.org/. For the client-side you can use it or use/combine it with something like angular/bootstrap. This depend of what do you men for client-side templating, if it has to include logic, or responsiveness...

Answer (score 2):

[Mustache](https://mustache.github.io/) is a nice template library that has implementations for many languages including Java and JavaScript. It provides everything that is needed for a template engine and avoids support for logic.